# VBA display a google static map in picture with long URL

Tags: vba, excel

I'm able to display a google static map in Excel.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Parent.Pictures.Insert theURL
```

This works fine but once my URL is longer than 1650 characters I get an error message.
It's the same when I use a shape to display the map.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("gMap").Fill.UserPicture theURL
```

Is there another way to display a google static map in Excel?
My URL I want to display could be <= 5000 characters. It's a map with a polyline.

There are URL examples:
URL with 1649 characters

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x600&path=enc%3Amym~h?g~uz`??e?a?q?a?k?c?u?e?s?i?}?m?{`?c?s?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?g?a?o?a?g?c?q?a?i?g?c`?a?i?m?w`?a?q?q?s`?c?i?s?u`?e?q?m?y`?e?q?o?}`?q?w`?a?g?o?w`?c?g?e?q?a?g?k?o`?o?y`?m?w`?q?w`?a?g?q?u`?a?g?i?y`?m?s`?a?g?k?y`?a?g?i?w`?a?g?e?{`??q?c?y`?g?w`?a?e?e?u?g?g`?m?}`?a?g?m?{`?o?y`?k?a`?i?a`?i?c`?o?s`?u?q`?i?y?o?}`?c?y?c?k`?a?o?k?{`?c?o?o?w`?a?g?m?w`?m?y`?a?g?m?g`?i?y?q?{`?c?o?e?u`?o?m`?a?g?e?c`?d?u?f?c?z?`?b`?b?``?b?f`?a?f??h?`?z??h`?d?|??z?c?f`?i?j??d`??d??z??p?c?d`?i?d??h`?c?h??d`?c?z?a?b??d`?c?~?i?v?k?h?c?b`?k?j?e?h??~?n?b`?c?d??d`?i?b`?u?f?u?`?o?e?u`?q?w`?q?w`?c?e?q?g`?o?y?k?k?}?y?w?g`?s?}?g?i?}?i`?e?e?u?g`?a?e?s?m`?i?c`?c?o?e?{?a?m??k?e?c`?e?a`?a?g?u?o`?a?g?a?e?m?i`?i?{???q?o`?k?w?e?m?m?m`?m?i`?u?m`?c?e?e?m?s?u`??q?i?y?y?k`?a?e?u?q`?q?w`?a?i?q?w`?m?w`?u?u`?s?s`?u?s`?c?g?s?q`?s?q`?e?k?m?m`?q?u`?c?e?o?c`?g?}?b?ca?c?{?m?c?o?n?w?|?c?b?u?r?y?d`?q?v`?s?|`?u?r`?g?n?k?v?g?l?i?n?u?m?a`?u?e?a?g`?y?e?c?e`?y?e?c?g`?u?i?e?c`?{?e?c?a`?y?g?e?a`?e`?{?}?{?h?a`?v?}?~?a?d?m?f`?g?n`?i?~`?e?z`?o?t`?c?f?m?|`?a?f?i?|`?k?v`?g?|`??v?a?~?c?z?`?ba??|?c?d?}?r?}?f`?q?r?e?l?m?l?a`?z?i?d?}?n?y?h?g?j?e?l?e?v?g?x`??|`?d?|`?`?l`?e?v`?d?z`?`?n?j?x`??f?h?z`??f?j?|`?b?t?f?v`?h?v`??f?p?|`?d?p?h?t`??v`?g?|`?c?p??~`?b?l?f?``?n?``?`?d?n?x?h?n?p?d`?r?l`?j?v?r?l`?t?p`?h?r?b?d?f?r?f?x?b?l?`?l?b?l?f?d`?`?f?b?h`?`?z??h?c?l`??f?c?l`?j?p`?n?r`?b?f?t?r`?d?n?f?v`?m?z?{?~?s?|?a`?|?a`?v?c?`?k?j?m?n?a`?z?c?b?a`?x?c`?|?c?b?a`?|?q?n?a`?z?e?b?y?x?{?~?`?d`?`?z?}?f`?i?d`??f??l`??r`?v?l`?t?p`?`?f?x?n`?t?~?x?d`?v?b`?j?t?`?b?j?p?h?j?b?b?z?``?v?``?h?j`??p`??f?j?z?|?b?v?a?h?b?v?r?z?m?``?w?b?c?~?{?f?e?b`?}?``?q?h?a?d`?w?
```

URL with 1653 characters

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x600&path=enc%3Amym~h?g~uz`??e?a?q?a?k?c?u?e?s?i?}?m?{`?c?s?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?g?a?o?a?g?c?q?a?i?g?c`?a?i?m?w`?a?q?q?s`?c?i?s?u`?e?q?m?y`?e?q?o?}`?q?w`?a?g?o?w`?c?g?e?q?a?g?k?o`?o?y`?m?w`?q?w`?a?g?q?u`?a?g?i?y`?m?s`?a?g?k?y`?a?g?i?w`?a?g?e?{`??q?c?y`?g?w`?a?e?e?u?g?g`?m?}`?a?g?m?{`?o?y`?k?a`?i?a`?i?c`?o?s`?u?q`?i?y?o?}`?c?y?c?k`?a?o?k?{`?c?o?o?w`?a?g?m?w`?m?y`?a?g?m?g`?i?y?q?{`?c?o?e?u`?o?m`?a?g?e?c`?d?u?f?c?z?`?b`?b?``?b?f`?a?f??h?`?z??h`?d?|??z?c?f`?i?j??d`??d??z??p?c?d`?i?d??h`?c?h??d`?c?z?a?b??d`?c?~?i?v?k?h?c?b`?k?j?e?h??~?n?b`?c?d??d`?i?b`?u?f?u?`?o?e?u`?q?w`?q?w`?c?e?q?g`?o?y?k?k?}?y?w?g`?s?}?g?i?}?i`?e?e?u?g`?a?e?s?m`?i?c`?c?o?e?{?a?m??k?e?c`?e?a`?a?g?u?o`?a?g?a?e?m?i`?i?{???q?o`?k?w?e?m?m?m`?m?i`?u?m`?c?e?e?m?s?u`??q?i?y?y?k`?a?e?u?q`?q?w`?a?i?q?w`?m?w`?u?u`?s?s`?u?s`?c?g?s?q`?s?q`?e?k?m?m`?q?u`?c?e?o?c`?g?}?b?ca?c?{?m?c?o?n?w?|?c?b?u?r?y?d`?q?v`?s?|`?u?r`?g?n?k?v?g?l?i?n?u?m?a`?u?e?a?g`?y?e?c?e`?y?e?c?g`?u?i?e?c`?{?e?c?a`?y?g?e?a`?e`?{?}?{?h?a`?v?}?~?a?d?m?f`?g?n`?i?~`?e?z`?o?t`?c?f?m?|`?a?f?i?|`?k?v`?g?|`??v?a?~?c?z?`?ba??|?c?d?}?r?}?f`?q?r?e?l?m?l?a`?z?i?d?}?n?y?h?g?j?e?l?e?v?g?x`??|`?d?|`?`?l`?e?v`?d?z`?`?n?j?x`??f?h?z`??f?j?|`?b?t?f?v`?h?v`??f?p?|`?d?p?h?t`??v`?g?|`?c?p??~`?b?l?f?``?n?``?`?d?n?x?h?n?p?d`?r?l`?j?v?r?l`?t?p`?h?r?b?d?f?r?f?x?b?l?`?l?b?l?f?d`?`?f?b?h`?`?z??h?c?l`??f?c?l`?j?p`?n?r`?b?f?t?r`?d?n?f?v`?m?z?{?~?s?|?a`?|?a`?v?c?`?k?j?m?n?a`?z?c?b?a`?x?c`?|?c?b?a`?|?q?n?a`?z?e?b?y?x?{?~?`?d`?`?z?}?f`?i?d`??f??l`??r`?v?l`?t?p`?`?f?x?n`?t?~?x?d`?v?b`?j?t?`?b?j?p?h?j?b?b?z?``?v?``?h?j`??p`??f?j?z?|?b?v?a?h?b?v?r?z?m?``?w?b?c?~?{?f?e?b`?}?``?q?h?a?d`?w?v?d?
```

Both URLs work when you copy them to your browser.

Comment: Use [bit.ly](https://bitly.com) to shorten the URL ?

Comment: @peter This may work. Is there a way to send the long URL to bit.ly and receive the short one via VBA?

Comment: ok, I found a way to do this via VBA but you need a token for bit.ly and I want to share the workbook but then I would share my token.

Comment: Can you supply an example problem URL to aid with testing?

Comment: URL abbreviators (forgive the made up word) aren't allowed here it seems due to their tendency to break and possibility may link to malicious code. However I did test and produce the following which I can't post as an answer. https://pastebin.com/udZsssB3

Comment: You might use consider using something more stable https://goo.gl/ and linked to your account.

Comment: Have you tried to download the image by the URL to temp folder, and then insert the image to the worksheet from the file?

Comment: @QHarr  - From goo.gl website "As of March 30, 2018, we will be turning down support for goo.gl URL shortener"

Comment: @dbmitch Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @omegastripes : This sounds interesting but how can I download the image to a temp folder?

Comment: Maybe  URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon"

Comment: I tested my function against your second URL (I had to concatenate several times to get one final string variable) and it worked but I do prefer @omegastripes suggestion.

Comment: @QHarr isn't omegastripes suggestion the same, download the image to folder and then insert it?

Comment: @omegastripes suggested downloading to a folder. I simply recommended a method, based on that, to achieve it i.e. urlmon. The other link I gave for pastebin in comments above achieved the same thing using the suggestion of a tinyURL (but I couldn't post that part as an answer).

Comment: @QHarr now I got it. Thanks. The only better solution would be to display a browser window in Excel but seems not work in newer Excel versions.

Comment: For security reasons you can't do Microsoft Web Browser anymore I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using @Omegastripes idea of downloading to a folder first. My function in the comments, which converted to tinyURL also worked but can't be posted. Downloading to a folder is more robust however.

**Note**:

If on 32-bit remove the word `PtrSafe`

**Code:**

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub DownloadPic()

    Dim url As String
    Dim fileLocation As String

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x600&path="
    url = url & "enc%3Amym~h?g~uz??e?a?q?a?k?c?u?e?s?i?}?m?{?c?s?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?i?a?g?a?o?a?g?c?q?a?i?g?c?a?i?m?w?a?q?q?s?c?i?s?u?e?q?m?y?e?q?o?}?q?w?a?g?o?w?c?g?e?q?a?g?k?o?o?y?m?w?q?w?a?g?q?u?a?g?i?y?m?s?a?g?k?y?a?g?i?w?a?g?e?{??q?c?y?g?w?a?e?e?u?g?g?m?}?a?g?m?{?o?y?k?a?i?a?i?c?o?s?u?q?i?y?o?}?c?y?c?k?a?o?k?{?c?o?o?w?a?g?m?w?m?y?a?g?m?g?i?y?q?{?c?o?e?u?o?m?a?g?e?c?d?u?f?c?z??b?b??b?f`?a?f??h?`?z??h`?d?|??z?c?f`?i?j??d`??d??z??p?c?d`?i?d??h`?c?h??d`?c?z?a?b??d`?c?~?i?v?k?h?c?b`?k?j?e?h??~?n?b`?c?d??d`?i?b`?u?f?u?`?o?e?u`?q?w`?q?w`?c?e?q?g`?o?y?k?k?}?y?w?g`?s?}?g?i?}?i`?e?e?u?g`?a?e?s?m`?i?c`?c?o?e?{?a?m??k?e?c`?e?a`?a?g?u?o`?a?g?a?e?m?i`?i?{???q?o`?k?w?e?m?m?m`?m?i`?u?m`?c?e?e?m?s?u`??q?i?y?y?k`?a?e?u?q`?q?w`?a?i?q?w`?m?w`?u?u`?s?s`?u?s`?c?g?s?q`?s?q`?e?k?m?m`?q?u`?c?e?o?c`?g?}?b?ca?c?{?m?c?o?n?w?|?c?b?u?r?y?d`?q?v`?s?|`?u?r`?g?n?k?v?g?l?i?n?u?m?a`?u?e?a?g`?y?e?c?e`?y?e?c?g`?u"
    url = url & "?i?e?c`?{?e?c?a`?y?g?e?a`?e`?{?}?{?h?a`?v?}?~?a?d?m?f`?g?n`?i?~`?e?z`?o?t`?c?f?m?|`?a"
    url = url & "?f?i?|`?k?v`?g?|`??v?a?~?c?z?`?ba??|?c?d?}?r?}?f`?q?r?e?l?m?l?a`?z?i?d?}?n?y?h?g?j?e?l?e?v?g?x`??|`?d?|`?`?l`?e?v`?d?z`?`?n?j?x`??f?h?z`??f?j?|`?b?t?f?v`?h?v`??f?p?|`?d?p?h?t`??v`?g?|`?c?p??~`?b?l?f??n??`?d?n?x?h?n?p?d`?r?l`?j?v?r?l`?t?p`?h?r?b?d?f?r?f?x?b?l?`?l?b?l?f?d`?`?f?b?h`?`?z??h?c?l`??f?c?l`?j?p`?n?r`?b?f?t?r`?d?n?f?v`?m?z?{?~?s?|?a`?|?a`?v?c?`?k?j?m?n?a`?z?c?b?a`?x?c`?|?c?b?a`?|?q?n?a`?z?e?b?y?x?{?~?`?d`?`?z?}?f`?i?d`??f??l`??r`?v?l`?t?p`?`?f?x?n`?t?~?x?d`?v?b`?j?t?`?b?j?p?h?j?b?b?z??v??h?j`??p`??f?j?z?|?b?v?a?h?b?v?r?z?m??w?b?c?~?{?f?e?b?}?``?q?h?a?d?w?v?d?"
    fileLocation = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder\Test.png"

    If URLDownloadToFile(0, url, fileLocation, 0, 0) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "downloaded"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Parent.Pictures.Insert fileLocation
        Kill fileLocation
    Else
        Debug.Print "failed"
    End If

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: In sheet]

Comment: Your solution works well it's just a little slow but I think I can life with it.

Comment: I don't know what else you have going on in the sheet. Remember you can optimize code is many circumstances by switching off screenupdating, calculation mode to manual etc at the start, and restore settings at the end. There are lots of posts about that.